# Maven : only deploy root project

Tags: maven

I have a root pom.xml which has :

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

Now I want to install all modules, but deploy only root project (push artifact to Nexus, but not artifacts of child's), **without editing poms of children porjects**. How should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: The artifact of the root project is only a POM file, isn't it?

Comment: No it's not, it's a zip file and I need to push it to Nexus.

Comment: If your "root pom.xml" is an aggregator, then it requires packaging "pom". How is the zip-file created?

Comment: this is a front-end project (nodejs), we use the root project to build child modules, and build zip file of several directories

Comment: zip file is generated by maven-assembly-plugin

Comment: Ideally, you would move your front-end project into `<module>C</module>`

Comment: @Steve C Yes I already did that, the problem is that one child project does not deploy but can only install. And I do not have the permission to change any file in that project. I need to deploy the zip file of root project which contains only a part of every project artifact.

Comment: If it's the root project then `mvn deploy --non-recursive`; otherwise if it's module C then `mvn deploy --projects :C`.